# Custom post type archive pagination query issue

Tags: wp-query, pagination, custom-post-type-archives

I'm using the following query to paginate a custom post type archive. The number of posts on the first page is 11 (due to the page layout) and 12 on the following pages. The problem is that while the posts are displayed correctly as set per page, on the second page the query starts from the 13th post skipping the 12th that should normally appear there first, so it gets skipped. This doesn't happen on the next pages, only on page 2. Any ideas?

```
<?php 
        if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
                $paged = get_query_var('paged');
            } else if ( get_query_var('page') ) {
                $paged = get_query_var('page');
            } else {
                $paged = 1;
            }
        if (is_paged()) {
            $offset = ( $paged - 1 ) * 12;
            $no = 12;
        }
        if (!is_paged()) {
            $offset = ( $paged - 1 ) * 11;
            $no = 11;
        }
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type'=> 'myarchive',
                        'orderby' => 'date',
                        'order'    => 'DESC',
                        'posts_per_page' => $no,
                        'meta_key' => 'no_photo',
                        'meta_value' => 0,
                        'paged' => $paged
                );
?>
```

Comment: I'm still trying to work this out. But it's a dead end. any ideas anyone?